# Sequelize restrict update if many-to-many relation established

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

In general I have a goal to restrict any update of an entity if it's binded to anything.

To be specific I have two models: `Order` and `Good`. They have many-to-many relation.

```
const Good = sequelize.define('good' , { name:Sequelize.STRING });
const Order = sequelize.define('order' , { });
//M:N relation
Good.belongsToMany(Order, { through: 'GoodsInOrders' });
Order.belongsToMany(Good, { through: 'GoodsInOrders' });
```

I have tried to set `onUpdate: 'NO ACTION'` and `onUpdate: 'RESTRICT'` inside `belongsToMany` association defining but it has no effect.
Here is the code to reproduce my manipulations with goods and order

```
//creating few goods
const good1 = await Good.create({ name:'Coca-Cola' });
const good2 = await Good.create({ name:'Hamburger' });
const good3 = await Good.create({ name:'Fanta' });

//creating an order
const order = await Order.create();

//adding good1 and good2 to the order
await order.addGoods([good1,good2]);

//It's ok to update good3 since no orders contains It
await good3.update( { name:'Pepsi' });

//But I need to fire an exeption if I try to update any goods belonged to order
//There should be an error because we previously added good1 to order
await good1.update( { name:'Sandwich' });
```

I have no clue how to restrict it in a simple way.
Surely we always can add `beforeUpdate` hook on `Good` model but I would like to avoid this kind of complications.

I will be glad to any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said I was looking for simpler alternative to hooks but many researches after all led me to nowhere.

My solution was to declare the `beforeUpdate` hook inside `Good` model so inital definition

```
const Good = sequelize.define('good' , { name : Sequelize.STRING } );
```

was transformed into this

```
const Good = sequelize.define('good', {
    name: Sequelize.STRING
}, {
    hooks: {
        beforeUpdate: async (instance, options) => {
            if ((await instance.getOrders()).length)
                return Promise.reject('error');
            return Promise.resolve();

        }
    }
});
```

So here we add the hook that fires every time before update particular good.
It makes inner request of list of orders that contains current good.

```
(await instance.getOrders()).length
```

And depends on the result it either fire an exception if the list isn't empty or  just return resolved promise that means that everything ok and current good can be updated.